# How can I remove commas or whatever from within a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, replace

I like to know how I can remove commas or whatever from within a string.

Here I have this array witch I converted to string, and I replace the dots or exclamation marks with an empty string. But how I can remove the commas within the strings?

```
let array3 = ['Mateo','Gusta,vo','Silv,ia!','Seba,stian.'];


function toString (convert){
    return convert.toString().replace(/[!.]/g, '');
}

console.log(toString(array3));
```

Comment: You need to map through the array, run the regex replace function and push each item to a new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the commas to the list of characters to be replaced with empty strings:

```
function toString (convert) {
    return convert.toString().replace(/[!.,]/g, '');
    // Here ------------------------------^
}
```

**EDIT:**
To address the concern the the comments, you could `map` the array and apply the regex to each string in it individually, and only then call `toString` on it:

```js
function toString (convert) {
    return convert.map(s => s.replace(/[!.,]/g, '')).toString();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But i can't remove the commas between the strings, only from the inside. example the comma inside 'Gusta,vo'. Is there any way?

Comment: @SebastianRosasBruno sure, see my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

just add comma in the

> replace return convert.toString().replace(/[!.,]/g, '');

```js
let array3 = ['Mateo','Gusta,vo','Silv,ia!','Seba,stian.'];


function toString (convert){
    return convert.toString().replace(/[!.,]/g, '');
}

console.log(toString(array3));
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But i can't remove the commas between the strings, only from the inside. example the comma inside 'Gusta,vo'. Is there any way?

Comment: @SebastianRosasBruno it's already removed, click _run code snipped_ and you will see that there is no comma

Comment: @SebastianRosasBruno So you do not want to remove the comma Gusta,vo but just the seperater one's ? Because with current code all the comma's are gone.

Answer (score 1):

You can map each string before joining (or using `.toString()`) the array's items:

```js
let array3 = ['Mateo', 'Gusta,vo', 'Silv,ia!', 'Seba,stian.'];

function toString(convert) {
  return convert
    .map(str => str.replace(/[,!.]/g, ''))
    .join(', ');
}

console.log(toString(array3));
```